# Dynamically replace substring in an given data(XML to fixed length)

Tags: xslt-2.0

Actually I have started with my XSLT work recently, I am facing difficulty in solving one of the requirement.

I am trying to fetch an substring from DATA element in the mentioned input i,e is ECHO and OKAY these codes need to be replaced with the values present under CODE/ECHO and CODE/OKAY in the same input. I had tried storing the substring in a variable and as the variable value and tag value would be same, I have tried to fetch that in `<xsl:value-of select="Root/CODES/$String" />`. But its not working.

Is it that we cant use variables in the XPATHS or there is some other representation which needs to be used? Could anyone please help me with this.

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:param name="break" select="'&#xA;'" />
<xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:variable name="String" select="substring(DATA, (string-length(substring(DATA,0,77)) + 1), 4)" />

        <xsl:variable name="String1" >
            <xsl:value-of select="Root/CODES/$String" />
        </xsl:variable> 
        <xsl:value-of select="$break" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$String1" />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

INPUT:

```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <ROOT>
        <INPUT>
            <I_FILENAME>ERES</I_FILENAME>
        </INPUT>
        <CODES>
             <ECHO>A1</ECHO>
             <OKAY>A2</OKAY> 
        </CODES>
        <TABLES>
            <T_ER>
                <item>
                    <DATA> HEADERERESRGCITIS220190301124112000000RGERSD46</DATA>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <DATA>000000    ABCD   EF     0000000000 2018-11-060000000000EF 000000000000010000A100400300000000000XXXXXX 000{  P 2018-11-05</DATA>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <DATA>000000    ABCD   EF     0000000000 2018-11-060000000000EF 000000000000010000A200400300000000000XXXXXX 000{  P 2018-11-05</DATA>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <DATA>TRAILERERESRGCITIS220190301124112000000001570000</DATA>
                </item>
            </T_ER>
        </TABLES>
    </ROOT>
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
         HEADERERESRGCITIS220190301124112000000RGERSD46
     000000    ABCD   EF     0000000000 2018-11-060000000000EF 000000000000010000A100400300000000000XXXXXX 000{  P 2018-11-05
     000000    ABCD   EF     0000000000 2018-11-060000000000EF 000000000000010000A200400300000000000XXXXXX 000{  P 2018-11-05
```

Comment: Can you simplify the input data for the question? I am struggling to see in those long strings which parts you want to replace but in general `substring`, `concat` or `replace` should do.

Answer (score 0):

I get the impression that you are imagining that when you write

```
Root/CODES/$String
```

and the value of `$String` is `"ECHO"`, then this is equivalent to writing

```
Root/CODES/ECHO
```

That's not how variables work. Variables represent values, not fragments of expression text (XPath is not a macro language). What `Root/CODES/$String` actually means is `Root/CODES/"ECHO"` that is, 'for every element in `Root/CODES`, return the string `"ECHO"`'.

I think what you are looking for is something like

```
Root/CODES/*[name()=$String]
```